# Counting using DictReader

Tags: python, dictionary, count

Still new to Python, this is how far I've managed to get:

```
import csv
import sys
import os.path

#VARIABLES


reader = None
col_header = None
total_rows = None
rows = None

#METHODS


def read_csv(csv_file):
#Read and display CSV file w/ HEADERS
    global reader, col_header, total_rows, rows

#Open assign dictionaries to reader
    with open(csv_file, newline='') as csv_file:
        #restval = blank columns = - /// restkey = extra columns +
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=None, restkey='+', restval='-', delimiter=',',
                                quotechar='"')

        try:
            col_header = reader.fieldnames
            print('The headers: ' + str(reader.fieldnames))
            for row in reader:
                print(row)

            #Calculate number of rows
            rows = list(reader)
            total_rows = len(rows)
        except csv.Error as e:
            sys.exit('file {}, line {}: {}'.format(csv_file, reader.line_num, e))


def calc_total_rows():
    print('\nTotal number of rows: ' + str(total_rows))
```

My issue is that, when I attempt to count the number of rows, it comes up as 0 (impossible because csv_file contains 4 rows and they print on screen. 
I've placed the '#Calculate number of rows' code above my print row loop and it works, however the rows then don't print. It's as if each task is stealing the dictionary from one another? How do I solve this?

Comment: Where are you calling `read_csv()`?

Comment: Sorry, in another file called 'main.py'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `reader` object behaves like a file as its iterating through the CSV. Firstly you iterate through in the `for` loop, and print each row. Then you try to create a list from whats left - which is now empty as you've iterated through the whole file. The length of this empty list is 0.

Try this instead:

```
rows = list(reader)
for row in rows:
    print(row)

total_rows = len(rows)
```